# How to scroll up terminal till your previous command?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, terminal

Is there a way to scroll up the terminal right till your previous command, no more no less? 
Ubuntu or mac.

The goal is to quickly find the beginning of the previous command output without spending time on scrolling and searching for it.

Comment: Just type and run the command: `history` on Linux based OS terminal to see a list of all your previous commands in case your version of Ubuntu or MAC doesn't have a scrollable bar in your terminal.

Comment: @d3r1ck the goal is to quickly find beginning of the output from the previous command.

Comment: On Ubuntu and other Linux based OS, the terminal almost always have a scrollable bar but if it doesn't, you can install a different terminal software.

Comment: @d3r1ck What I'm asking is how to avoid scrolling and searching for your previous command and jump right to the beginning of the output.

Comment: I just answered your question. Check my answer.

Comment: I have exactly this problem and I'm not sure why is this question getting downvoted

Comment: <kbd>⌘ + ↑</kbd> ([Consider upvoting this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209635/what-functionality-do-marks-offer-in-the-el-capitan-terminal))

Answer (score -2):

If you are running a gnome-terminal (default GUI terminal on ubuntu) you can hit shift+ctrl+f, type your search terms, and hit enter. Still graphical, but no mouse required.

Or

Finding text in scrollback is a weakness of most terminal emulators; the only ones I know of that provide it are OS X Terminal and [Terminator](https://code.google.com/p/jessies/). That said, you could run [GNU screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) in any terminal and search its scrollback buffer in copy mode.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please clarify, how this feature is implemented in OS X Terminal?

Comment: I don't think it has been implemented in Mac OS X. I just know only of Linux, did it work for you on Linux?